# Como fazer um método de análise de string funcional?

Tags: java

Estou criando uma aplicação que simula um sistema de biblioteca, e para começar, é necessário efetuar o login inserindo um nome no campo de texto.
Esse é o método que eu criei para analisar o nome (eu quero apenas letras maiúsculas e espaços nessa string):

```
public boolean nomeConfere(String nome) {
    for(int n = 0; n < nome.length(); n++){
        if(nome.charAt(n) != 'A' || nome.charAt(n) != 'B' || nome.charAt(n) != 'C' || 
                nome.charAt(n) != 'D' || nome.charAt(n) != 'E' || nome.charAt(n) != 'F' || 
                nome.charAt(n) != 'G' || nome.charAt(n) != 'H' || nome.charAt(n) != 'I' || 
                nome.charAt(n) != 'J' || nome.charAt(n) != 'K' || nome.charAt(n) != 'L' || 
                nome.charAt(n) != 'M' || nome.charAt(n) != 'N' || nome.charAt(n) != 'O' || 
                nome.charAt(n) != 'P' || nome.charAt(n) != 'Q' || nome.charAt(n) != 'R' || 
                nome.charAt(n) != 'S' || nome.charAt(n) != 'T' || nome.charAt(n) != 'U' || 
                nome.charAt(n) != 'V' || nome.charAt(n) != 'W' || nome.charAt(n) != 'X' || 
                nome.charAt(n) != 'Y' || nome.charAt(n) != 'Z' || nome.charAt(n) != 'Ç' ||
                nome.charAt(n) != ' '){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O nome não foi digitado corretamente.", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;

        }
    }
    this.nome = nome; 
    return true;
}
```

Mas ele não está funcionando. Eu testei a aplicação após implementá-lo e coloquei um nome apenas com esses caracteres no campo de texto, mas o JOptionPane de erro que não deveria aparecer, apareceu. Alguma solução?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está usando OR na condição. Ou seja, se o nome for diferente de A OU diferente de B ...

Considere que o nome é ADAO.

```
"A" != "A": false
"A" != "B": true
```

A comparação com C não é nem realizada, pois `false || true` resulta em `true`.

Você pode resolver isto mudando para AND ao invés de OR. Assim somente se todas as condições forem verdadeiras é que seu bloco será executado.

Se quiser deixar o código mais enxuto você pode usar [Regular Expressions](http://aprenda.vidageek.net/aprenda/regex) para fazer está verificação.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando expressão regular o seu código ficará mais simples e fácil de dar manutenção. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
public Boolean nomeConfere(String nome) {
  if (!nome.matches("^[A-Z ]+$")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O nome não foi digitado corretamente.", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

A expressão regular acima testa se a `String` tem caracteres de A à Z maiúsculo ou espaços do inicio ao fim.